# Generate a "socket" from inputstream and outputstream

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I have one inputstream and one outputstream. From these two, I can get tcp request and also write response. Now, I want to generate a socket which use these two as its i/o stream and thus I can call `SSLSocket.createSocket()` function on it to generate a `SSLSocket`. With SSLSocket, I can get all message in plain text.

I think I should implement `SocketImpl` class to make such a socket. But `SocketImpl` has a lot of abstract methods. Which methods should I implement? Or is there any other way to do it?

(The socket doesn't need to connect to anything, I only need to read and write to it.)

**UPDATE:**
So to make it clear, I want to create a socket which doesn't connect to anything. I can write something to its inputstream which can then be read by others. Also this socket should be able to be used as a parameter for SSLSocket.createSocket()

Comment: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: plz explain the requisite..

Comment: I want to do man in the middle attack but don't want to parse the SSL packet or decrypt manually. So I want to use the SSLSocket which can be build on a socket and help me to get the plaintext. But what I have is two stream.

Comment: me also waiting for reply of this question..

Comment: You can't do what you're asking. You can do MITM but not in that way. Start again with your actual requirement, not some half-imagined solution that can't be completed.